# Get sed to ignore special characters in file?

Tags: bash, sed, cron

I'm trying to extract user's crontabs so as to view them together. The initial problem I ran into was that the crontab file (From crontab -l) contains a lot of commented lines placed there by the system to explain the file's function. I stole a sed snippet to deal with this that deletes lines starting with comments and replaces the rest of lines following comments with blanks. (As best as I understand it.)

Here's an example crontab I'd like to capture:

```
0 0 5 * * /home/thornegarvin/myscript.sh
```

The sed code I'm using is: (With croneditor.temp containing the crontab)

```
sed '/^[[:blank:]]*#/d;s/#.*//' croneditor.temp
```

I think that the command is matching the *s in the file as comments and then deleting the line, but I'm not sure if that's why the command is failing.
I need a version of this command or another one entirely that works as I intended (Grabbing crontabs from the output of crontab -l).

Comment: `grep -v '^#' file`?

Comment: Why do you not show us either the output or the error message if there is?

Comment: Your `sed` command is working in my box. Although I think the second `sed` command (`s/#.*//`) is superfluous.

Comment: @Jdamian: It is not superfluous as he wants to remove the trailing comments (after the cron commands)

Comment: @Cyrus: no, for the very same reason above